# Checking if one of more strings is empty in array/enum

Tags: java, enums

So I am making a small program to log in to. I have 4 forms that you need to fill in and if you click the button to login, then I want to check if the forms are filled and if not you get a message saying which form you still need to fill in. I thought of 2 ways for doing this. one easier way than the other.
The easy way:

```
static String [] Check = {SendMail.FEText, SendMail.FWText, SendMail.TEText, SendMail.TWText};

    public static boolean fullFilled() {
        for (String s: Check) {
            if (s.equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Je bent vergeten om iets in te vullen.", "Vergeten", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And another one with an `enum`, but I have no idea how to finish this:

```
public enum Check {
        FACEBOOK_EMAIL("FaceBook emailadres", SendMail.FEText),
        FACEBOOK_WACHTWOORD("FaceBook wachtwoord", SendMail.FWText),
        TOTO_EMAIL("Toto emailadres", SendMail.TEText),
        TOTO_WACHTWOORD("Toto wachtwoord", SendMail.TWText);

        public String formName;
        public String stringName;

        Check(String formName, String stringName) {
            this.formName = formName;
            this.stringName = stringName;
        }

    }

    public static boolean fullFilled() {
        for (String s: Check) {
            if (s.equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Je bent vergeten om " + s.formName + "iets in te vullen.", "Vergeten", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I want the message to say "Je bent vergeten om FaceBook emailadres in te vullen." if you forgot to fill in the `facebookemail(FEText)`

Comment: `for (Check check: Check.values())`?

Comment: uhm. I don't know how to use enums ;(

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I want this to check if one of those things in the arrays is empty, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all the values of that enum, and then for each one, check if the `stringName` is blank.  If it is, you add it to a `messageBody`, and display that in the dialog if it isn't empty.

Note that the check below ignores all white space, which is probably what you want.

```
public static boolean fullFilled() {
    String messageBody = "";
    for (Check check: Check.values()) {
        if (check.stringName.trim().isEmpty()) {
            messageBody = messageBody + "Je bent vergeten om " + check.formName + "iets in te vullen." + "\n";
        }
    }
    if(!messageBody.trim().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, messageBody, "Vergeten", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'll check this out as soon as I get on my pc, thank you.

Comment: I did this, but when I fill in the first form, then it says that I didn't fill in the first form. I think that this is happening, because it checks if one of the forms is empty and if that is true, then it always returns with the first formName. is there a way to make it return the formName of the form that isn't filled?

Comment: I just took your algorithm and changed it to support Enums.  I didn't bother to check the logic.  There was a bug - it was essentially only checking the first form field.  I've corrected this.  I'm not quite certain what you are asking in your comment.  Would you like to list all empty fields in the same dialog message?

Comment: I'll check it as soon as I get home. Thank you very much.